How to disable printing the file name in the go test output?
Is it possible to avoid printing the go file name in the go test output?
For example, I have this print out:
=== RUN   TestValidateFreezeErrors_MarshalJSON
    validate_freeze_test.go:125: Given freeze validate errors
    validate_freeze_test.go:127:    Test 0: only inventory parse errors
    utils.go:16:    ✅   Should return no error
    utils.go:16:    ✅   Should return the expected JSON
    validate_freeze_test.go:127:    Test 1: only cross-check errors
    utils.go:16:    ✅   Should return no error
    utils.go:16:    ✅   Should return the expected JSON
    validate_freeze_test.go:127:    Test 2: both error types
    utils.go:16:    ✅   Should return no error
    utils.go:16:    ✅   Should return the expected JSON
--- PASS: TestValidateFreezeErrors_MarshalJSON (0.00s)

I would like to print it like so:
=== RUN   TestValidateFreezeErrors_MarshalJSON
    Given freeze validate errors
        Test 0: only inventory parse errors
        ✅   Should return no error
        ✅   Should return the expected JSON
        Test 1: only cross-check errors
        ✅   Should return no error
        ✅   Should return the expected JSON
        Test 2: both error types
        ✅   Should return no error
        ✅   Should return the expected JSON
--- PASS: TestValidateFreezeErrors_MarshalJSON (0.00s)

I tried looking at go help test and go help testflag but I can't seem to find any options for it.  So maybe there's a way to programmatically turn it off.

Can you share your test file? Also, are you running your tests with -v flag?

Sure, it's possible. It's even the default behaviour AFAIK. Simple unit tests (I just ran a few) with go test -v ./some/pkg are pretty much the output you're looking for. I suspect that you're using some modules to enhance your test suite, or you may be including t.Log calls in the unit tests themselves, which print out the file names. Either way, why would you not want that information? If a test fails, I think it's kind of useful to see what file & line number the failing test can be found at.

@MilosStojanovic Indeed I'm running with -v flag. If I remove it, then I won't be able to see the above outputs -- that are generated with t.Logf(...)

@EliasVanOotegem when I remove the -v flag, I will only see "ok    path/to/folder"

I see that you are using t.Log for printing that information. In short answer: No, is not possible to remove the name.
Long Answer :
The Testing package of go when using the Log Fuction it decorate the String that you are sending :
// decorate prefixes the string with the file and line of the call site
// and inserts the final newline if needed and indentation spaces for formatting.
// This function must be called with c.mu held.
func (c *common) decorate(s string, skip int) string {
    frame := c.frameSkip(skip)
    file := frame.File
    line := frame.Line
    if file != "" {
        if *fullPath {
            // If relative path, truncate file name at last file name separator.
        } else if index := strings.LastIndexAny(file, `/\`); index >= 0 {
            file = file[index+1:]
        }
    } else {
        file = "???"
    }
    if line == 0 {
        line = 1
    }
    buf := new(strings.Builder)
    // Every line is indented at least 4 spaces.
    buf.WriteString("    ")
    fmt.Fprintf(buf, "%s:%d: ", file, line)
    lines := strings.Split(s, "\n")
    if l := len(lines); l > 1 && lines[l-1] == "" {
        lines = lines[:l-1]
    }
    for i, line := range lines {
        if i > 0 {
            // Second and subsequent lines are indented an additional 4 spaces.
            buf.WriteString("\n        ")
        }
        buf.WriteString(line)
    }
    buf.WriteByte('\n')
    return buf.String()
}

And no. There is not an option to skip this decorate.

thanks! i suppose i'll just leave it at that :)
